# How to correctly pull data from XML feed via PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I've got an XML feed that I want to pull from via PHP, here's the XML:

```
<PhysicalCar>
    <Car IDValue="fr">
        <CarInformation>
            ...INFORMATION...
        </CarInformation>
        <CarModel IDValue="lx-red">
            <Name>Luxurious Frodo - Red</Name>
        </CarModel>
        <CarModel IDValue="kx-blue">
            <Name>Kajun Frodo - Blue</Name>
        </CarModel>
        <CarModel IDValue="bx-purple">
            <Name>BMX Frodo - Purple</Name>
        </CarModel>
    </Car>
    <Car IDValue="gk">
        <CarInformation>
            ...INFORMATION...
        </CarInformation>
        <CarModel IDValue="jr-red">
            <Name>Joyride Turbo - Red</Name>
        </CarModel>
        <CarModel IDValue="yy-blue">
            <Name>Yellow Turbo - Blue</Name>
        </CarModel>
        <CarModel IDValue="qq-purple">
            <Name>Quilting Turbo - Purple</Name>
        </CarModel>
    </Car>
    ...MORE CARS...
</PhysicalCar>
```

Following the XML above, there's roughly 50-100 "Car"s. I'm trying to write PHP code that will pass in a value, for example 'gk' and scan for a "Car" with the same IDValue. WHEN found, I want to cycle through each of the "CarModel"s and echo them out.

So for example, if 'gk' was passed in, this would be the output:

JoyrideTurbo - Red, Yellow Turbo - Blue, Quilting Turbo - Purple.

Here's my php code:

```
<?php
    $passedinvalue = 'gk';

    $xml = simplexml_load_file('myxml.xml')
    or die("Cannot create object");

    foreach ($xml->Car as $c) {
        if ($c->IDVAlue = $passedinvalue) {
            foreach ($c->CarModel as $cm) {
                echo $cm->Name;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

What would be the proper way to go about this PHP code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with XPath.

```
foreach($xml->xpath('//Car[@IDValue="' . $passedinvalue . '"]') as $car_models) {
   foreach($car_models->CarModel as $car_model) {
      echo $car_model->Name;
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it.